# Can I be friends with everybody while doing all the plots?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

Being a full-time approval junkie, I would like to make all the friends in X3 Albion Prelude, or at least befriend all the races (Argon, Boton, Teladi, Paranid, Split, Terran). Will completing the Albion Prelude questline, which seems to be all about the Commonwealth-Terran war (who knew we were such bastards?) irrepairably damage my relationship with Terrans and the ATF? Are there any quick ways to regain lost reputation with a faction?

Comment: Its doable, I've finished the plot while still friendly with everyone.

Comment: @spartacus how did you achieve this?

Comment: if you build up a bit of positive rep with the terrans before you start the plot missions, you can have enough left over so repairing it isn't too hard.  I started with poisoned paranid (because I love the overtuned hype so much) so my terran rep didn't start out too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time in main plot you can avoid ecxessive killing of Terran ships. And between mission you can repair reputation by trading, missions or killing Xenon ships in Segaris.

You can also minimize reputation loss by killing ships in as few attacks as possible, ramming them turbo engaged or using missiles are some of the least reputation-damaging options.

If your fight rating is small, there will be less enemies.